# Angular 5 routing with query string

Tags: angular, angular-routing, canactivate

I am writing my angular 5+ app and using `AuthGuardService` what I am doing is that I am redirecting from another `php` application which send me form data in query string

```
http://localhost:44200/#/users/save?first_name=John&last_name=Doe
```

the `AuthGuardService` properly redirect user to login if he is not logged in with following code

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot){
    if(localStorage.getItem('crmUser')){
      return true;
    }
    this.router.navigate(['/login'], { queryParams: {returnUrl: state.url},queryParamsHandling: 'merge' });
    return false;
}
```

But after login I can redirect to return url if it has no query string, I want to redirect user to same page with all query string.

Please guide me how to handle it.

Comment: ``queryParamsHandling : 'preserve' ``

Comment: You can put condition in your guard itself check that if url has your query string and match with your desired values if not then redirect to sample page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I did it. In your AuthGuard#canActivate add the following:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate{

  originRoute:ActivatedRouteSnapshot;

  constructor(private authentificationService: AuthChecker,
              private router: Router){}

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    if(localStorage.getItem('crmUser')){
       return true;
    }
    this.originRoute = route;
    this.router.navigate(['/login'], { queryParams: {returnUrl: state.url},queryParamsHandling: 'merge' });
    return false;


    }
  }

  public hasOriginRoute(): boolean{
    return this.originRoute != null;

  }
}
```

Now in your LoginComponent when login succeeded add:

```
if(this.authGuard.hasOriginRoute()){
   this.router.navigate(this.authGuard.originRoute.url.map((x) => x.path));
}
```